# Youtube Data API v2 : How to get videos of English language only?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to build a website based on youtube embedded videos.

For this I am using Youtube Data API v2.

With this I am getting videos but the problem is with the "language" used in videos or the description of the video is not "English" for all of the videos fetched.

I want to fetch only videos which have either their description or audio or both in "English language".
With description I mean the title of the video and it's meta description.

Please suggest any possible way to fetch videos with English language only using Youtube Data API v2.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The "lr" parameter is the simplest way that I know of in v2.
In your request, add the parameter lr=en to produce English only results.

For example, I wish to grab a list of published videos with the word "soccer" only in English, I would use the following:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=hrvatska&lr=en
```

This would output results only if they have *some* English in either the title or description/keywords, as opposed to pure Croatian results without this filter. This provides a higher quality result but it isn't perfect especially for English as there are many lingua franca terms in English that allows non-English vids to slip through but it provides a good result.

Source: Youtube API Devloper's Guide

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#lrsp

Comment: Hey this help me to improve the result set, but its not that all videos are in English only. But Yes I as said there's a improvement. Thanks.